# How to change Seaborn legend `fontsize` without changing `linestyle` as well?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

The default `fontsize` of the legend is too small. I am using Seaborn, and I can't increase `fontsize` of legend without affecting the `linestyle`. Is there a way to change the fontsize without affecting `linestyle`?

```
ax = sns.lineplot(data=drinkability_df, x='threshold', y='undrinkable', hue='models_undrinkable', linewidth=2)
ax = sns.lineplot(data=drinkability_df, x='threshold', y='drinkable', hue='models_drinkable', linestyle='--', linewidth=2)
plt.title('Identifying Water Types By Thresholds', fontsize= 18)
plt.xlabel('Thresholds', fontsize= 16)
plt.ylabel('Drinkable Or Undrinkable', fontsize= 16)


style = ax.legend()
style_lines = style.get_lines()
for i in range(3,6):
    style_lines[i].set_linestyle("--")

plt.setp(ax.legend().get_texts(), fontsize=15);
```

[seaborn lineplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3v56.jpg)

[csv here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjWn_Ti3zTKEhe9q17T8cOYLhL-0KQ?e=U0MfVw)

Comment: `style = ax.legend(fontsize=20)` ?

Answer (score 0):

`ax.legend()` generates a new legend; `ax.get_legend()` returns the current one (if it exists).